# How to "counta" if some cell greater than 1 in Google Docs?

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I have this data in my Google Spreadsheet

```
Col1   Col2 
 1      X      
 1      
 2      A
 2      B
```

I want to make a formula to count Not Empty cell from `Col2` but with condition that `Col1 is greater than 1`

Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**countifs** can count based on multiple criteria.
Using it we can count only when:
Col1 is ">1"
and
Col2 is not empty (using wildcard "*" matching)

**=countifs(A1:A4, ">1", B1:B4, "*")**

[image]